# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.laf.AquaTableUI

Tags: java

I use ScrumWorks Pro on my Mac OS X,but an error occurred and the main error message is：

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.laf.AquaTableUI
```

I installed the oracle JDK8 and java version is 1.8.0_111.
I searched for a long time and hardly had this solution.But I found AquaTableUI class in openjdk8.

I want to know if apple.laf.AquaTableUI is only available in openjdk,but not in Oracle.If not, is there a solution?
Looking forward to your answer,Thanks.

Comment: The oracle and openjdk class libraries are the same in this respect.  My suggestion would be to make sure that your application is actually using the correct JDK.

Comment: @lscoughlin Thanks for your answer.Using the same version of JDK under Win7 can open this application.I don't think it's the cause of the JDK.

Comment: If that's the case then the cause is DEFINITELY the JDK, sort of.  Most likely the application itself is poorly packaged for MacOS ( includes and old JDK or some nonsense ).

Comment: as in, this isn't a java problem, this is a scrumworks pro problem.  It's not a free app though, so your best bet is to take it to their support.